# Is the matrix<> that we use in dlib for c++ essentially a vector at it's core?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, computer-vision, fpga, dlib

I am fairly new to dlib and I was pretty confused with the length() function used in the dnn_face_recognition.cpp code. On digging a bit I realized that the function returns the length of the input vector. I edited the code for my use and am using the same function for a matrix and it still runs fine. I wonder if the matrix used in dlib essentially a matrix at its core?

```
std::vector<sample_pair> edges;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < face_descriptors.size(); ++i)
    {
        //for (size_t j = i; j < face_descriptors.size(); ++j)
        {
            // Faces are connected in the graph if they are close enough.  Here we check if
            // the distance between two face descriptors is less than 0.6, which is the
            // decision threshold the network was trained to use.  Although you can
            // certainly use any other threshold you find useful.
            if (length(face_descriptors-read_face) < 0.6)
                edges.push_back(sample_pair(i,0));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this question means. What do you mean by "essentially a vector"? Is that "stores its elements in a `std::vector<>`"? Or "stores its elements contiguously, like a `std::vector`"? Or something else? And why would you care?

Comment: @MSalters I wanted to know whether it stores it's elements "in" a std::vector<>
I am trying to understand it's working in order to alter some functions around it.